New warning message on osX : no active key-value observers (KVO)
All of a sudden on a fairly large project, I've started getting the following warning message on osX machines.  I have no idea where it's coming from or why it just started.  I haven't upgraded my osX recently.

qt.qpa.window: <QNSWindow: 0x7f95fb8d58b0; contentView=<QNSView:
0x7f95fb8d52b0; QCocoaWindow(0x6000028db9c0,
window=QWidgetWindow(0x600003583780, name="PSDWidgetClassWindow"))>>
has active key-value observers (KVO)! These will stop working now that
the window is recreated, and will result in exceptions when the
observers are removed. Break in QCocoaWindow::recreateWindowIfNeeded
to debug.

The program works as usual without error, but the message is annoying.
I found the same error on another forum, but there was no solution.  Any help is appreciated.

We need further details. Some other results appear with a simple "qt recreateWindowIfNeeded" search query (such as this and this), which seem valid starting point for further research. You should try to reproduce the issue by creating a [mre] using your code as reference. We also need more environment details, starting with specific OS and Qt info.
